# Installing scikit learn on VS 2017 Python

Tags: python, visual-studio

Could someone please advise me how or direct me to an easy to follow resource for getting scikit learn set up as a library on VS 2017 Python? I am not talking about importing it into my own code, but actually allowing VS to recognise the library.

I have Python 2.7 on the 64x VS environment set up.

I've looked into the installation page on scikit learn website and it is very unclear to me.

I have already installed it on PyCharm , which was very simple with a few commands, yet VS is the sole IDE which is unable to see this library.

I'm fairly new to VS yet am finding it much more complicated to do simple things compared to other IDEs

Answer (score -1):

I think you should change your python environment of the VS 2017 to python 3.5 or 3.6 for 64-bit or something like that (python 3 instead of python 2 in general).